Tokenize string with different separators by regex in Python
I have an output string from another piece of software. It is as follows:
tstring = "12A/Ma1 $GJG (#G25)"

I would like to extract a simple list:
["Ma","GJG", "G25"]

in particular:
['the first two characters after the /', 'the characters after $ before the next space', 'the contents of the bracket without the #']

I've tried to do it as I would in Excel, with all kinds of find and match constructions, but I feel that regex is a better option. Although I don't know how to structure this.
Would anyone be able to help?

Using the information in Python's re HOWTO is more than sufficient to come up with a simple regular expression that does what you ask for. In fact, we just translate the English-language description of your matching criteria into regular expression syntax.
The resulting regular expression is as follows:
r"/(.{2}).*?\$(\S*).*?\(#(.*?)\)"

It uses three capture groups, the things in (unescaped) parentheses with .*? as filler in between. The .*? will non-greedily match anything. This is just to gobble up the characters we're not interested in.
First capture group is after the slash, any two characters.
Second capture group is after the dollar sign, anything but whitespace.
Third capture group is anything in the (escaped) parentheses, without the leading hash.
The following little script will produce the output you ask for:
import re

tstring = "12A/Ma1 $GJG (#G25)"

match = re.search(r"/(.{2}).*?\$(\S*).*?\(#(.*?)\)", tstring)
if match:
    print(list(match.groups()))
else:
    print("no match")

Prints:
['Ma', 'GJG', 'G25']

The cast to list is kind of optional; matches.groups() returns a tuple and you wanted a list.
...or just split
For a simple example such as yours (and provided the string always looks more or less the same) you could also do without the re module and use str.split() ... well, several times.
The idea is to split tstring according to the delimiters you describe. This is not so easy on the eyes (but then, regular expressions can also be a little bit ugly at times). It works only with string and list operations:
split_string = [
        tstring.split('/', maxsplit=1)[1][0:2],
        tstring.split('$', maxsplit=1)[1].split(' ')[0],
        tstring.split('(#', maxsplit=1)[1].split(')')[0]
]
print(split_string)

Same output as above.

Split your input string into parts, the ones you want to match and the ones in between:
.*?/    # Any characters until/including the first slash
(..)    # The next two characters (as a group)
.*?\$   # Any characters until/including the next dollar sign
(\S*)   # 0 or more non-space characters (as a group)
.*\(    # Any characters until/including the last opening parenthesis
(.*)    # Any characters (as a group)
\)      # The closing parenthesis

>>> import re
>>> tstring = "12A/Ma1 $GJG (#G25)"
>>> m = re.match(r'.*?/(..).*?\$(\S*).*\((.*)\)', tstring)
>>> m.groups()
('Ma', 'GJG', '#G25')


Nice concise explanation. Btw, you still need to lose the #

Not complicated but pretty basic, check out https://regex101.com/
import re
tstring = "12A/Ma1 $GJG (#G25)"
match1= re.findall("\/(..)", tstring)
match2= re.findall("\$(.*) ", tstring)
match3= re.findall("\(#(.*)\)", tstring)
print(match1[0])
print(match2[0])
print(match3[0])

Result
Ma
GJG
G25

Note that some \ are needed to escape regex syntax characters like / or $ to do this.
list = [match1[0],match2[0],match3[0]]

Will glue all results into a List.
['Ma', 'GJG', 'G25']


I really like your "divide and conquer" approach. But re.findall() will find all the matches. So in case of say an extra slash elsewhere "12A/Ma1 $GJG (#/G25)" (or repeated other pattern) one will get more matches. Granted, this is a problem with the test input size == 1.

@darked89 I get your point, however we can only work with what is given in the question
